# Converting PDF pages into images in Node.js using the pdf2pic package

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, npm

I'm attempting to convert PDF pages into images using the pdf2pic module.

```
import { fromPath } from "pdf2pic";

const options = {
  density: 700,
  saveFilename: "output_img",
  savePath: "./images",
  format: "jpeg",
  width: 2480,
  height: 3508,
};
const convert = fromPath("/path/to/pdf/sample.pdf", options);
const pageToConvertAsImage = 1;

convert(pageToConvertAsImage, { responseType: "image" })
  .then((resolve) => {
    console.log("Page 1 is now converted as image");
return resolve;
  });
```

**The above code works fine for converting a single image, but I need to convert the entire PDF into images.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to iterate through all the pages of the PDF. Try something like this,

```js
const options = {
  ...
}

...

const totalNumberOfPages = 10 // adjust according to number of pages in your PDF

// create an array of page numbers from 1 to the total number of pages
const pageNumbers = Array.from({ length: totalNumberOfPages }, (_, i) => i + 1)

// function to convert a single page
const convertPage = (pageNumber) => {
  return convert(pageNumber, { responseType: "image" })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Page ${pageNumber} is now converted as an image`)
    })
}

// Use Promise.all to convert all pages concurrently
Promise.all(pageNumbers.map(convertPage))
  .then(() => {
    console.log("All pages are converted successfully")
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error converting pages:", error)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and answer! Is using a loop the best solution for adding the image in the code?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that.